# What is some relevent scripture regarding having something stolen?

Tags: bible, forgiveness

I recently had some things stolen out of my car, and I vaguely remember reading somewhere in the New Testament that you shouldn't desire to get stolen items back. I've been searching for it, but I can't seem to find it.

Does anyone know the verse?
Also, is there any other encouraging scripture you could recommend on the topic?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because verse identification questions are now off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the verse you are looking for, it's sure to be this:

> **[Luke 6:29-30](http://www.esvbible.org/search/Luke+6%3A29-30/)** (ESV)
>   To one who strikes you on the cheek, offer the other also, and from one who takes away your cloak do not withhold your tunic either. Give to everyone who begs from you, and from one who takes away your goods do not demand them back.

Remember this is advice to YOU, not to the thief. We also know from Scripture that theft is wrong and there would be nothing intrinsically wrong with the thief being brought to justice. This verse is advice to you to guard your attitude. Worldly possessions will pass away anyway, they are not worth carrying a grudge over.

As far as your situation goes, I would recommend simply remembering that God takes care of his people. Though we may be sorely tried in this life, we know that God cares for us as a Father and not a hair falls from our head but that he knows it.

Comment: Thank you so much! That's the one! The thing that was eating at me was that they were the instruments that I lead worship with. I needed some scripture to hold close in the situation.

Answer (score 0):

**What is some relevent scripture regarding having something stolen?**

> 1 Corinthians 6:7  Now therefore there is utterly a fault among you,
>   because ye go to law one with another. Why do ye not rather take
>   wrong? why do ye not rather suffer yourselves to be defrauded?

The verse above is written to Christian s who are suing each other but the principle can be expended to cover instances of using restraint instead of exercising rights.

Another verse can be used to help us consider that our possessions are not so much ours but on loan from God.

> 1 Corinthians 4:7  For who maketh thee to differ from another? and
>   what hast thou that thou didst not receive? now if thou didst receive
>   it, why dost thou glory, as if thou hadst not received it?

There is a danger to those who focus on what they own.

> Luke 12:15  And he said unto them, Take heed, and beware of
>   covetousness: for a man's life consisteth not in the abundance of the
>   things which he possesseth.

The loss of something can help us turn from the grip possessions can have over us.

> Luke 18:22-25  Now when Jesus heard these things, he said unto him,
>   Yet lackest thou one thing: sell all that thou hast, and distribute
>   unto the poor, and thou shalt have treasure in heaven: and come,
>   follow me.   And when he heard this, he was very sorrowful: for he was
>   very rich.   And when Jesus saw that he was very sorrowful, he said,
>   How hardly shall they that have riches enter into the kingdom of God! 
>   For it is easier for a camel to go through a needle's eye, than for a
>   rich man to enter into the kingdom of God.

Comment: This answer is in error. Paul was pleading with the Corinthians not to go to the _secular_ authorities to settle disputes between Christians. In context he is saying, would not ye rather suffer yourselves to be defrauded than to expose that brother defrauds brother _before unbelievers_. Jesus himself tells us that is someone sins against you, confront him. Paul tells us to confront him, then if necessary bring him before the elders, then if necessary discontinue fellowship with him. Indeed, Paul exercises his right to appeal to Caesar in Acts 25- he would not then tell us not to appeal to ours